# SQL Server stored procedure showing syntax error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure which creates a table at runtime. The table columns and their data types for this dynamic table comes from another table already in place in database.

I am calling this stored procedure from C# console application code. The stored procedure is throwing a syntax error and I am totally not able to figure out what is causing this syntax error.

This is the stored procedure code I've written:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sproc_TableExists]
   @TableName NVARCHAR(128) 
      ,@Column1Name NVARCHAR(32)
      ,@Column1DataType NVARCHAR(32)
      ,@Column1Nullable NVARCHAR(32)
AS
   DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
   BEGIN
       IF( EXISTS (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName))
       BEGIN
            SET @SQLString = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + '( '+ @Column1Name + ' ' + @Column1DataType + ' '+ @Column1Nullable +')'
            EXEC (@SQLString)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @SQLString = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '( '+ @Column1Name + ' ' + @Column1DataType + ' '+ @Column1Nullable +')'
            EXEC (@SQLString)
        END
END
GO
```

Error I am getting calling it from code :

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the following line of code, when altering an existing table:

```
SET @SQLString = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + '( '+ @Column1Name + ' ' + @Column1DataType + ' '+ @Column1Nullable +')'
```

This generates the following output (as an example using a fake table\column name):

```
ALTER TABLE TableEx( ColumnEx NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL)
```

However, this is not a valid SQL statement.

If you want the behaviour to be to add a new column when the table already exists, use this instead:

```
SET @SQLString = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + ' ADD '+ @Column1Name + ' ' + @Column1DataType + ' '+ @Column1Nullable
```

Which will produce the output:

```
ALTER TABLE TableEx ADD ColumnEx NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
```

Note that if your intention is to change the name of a pre-existing column in a pre-existing table you will need to test for this separately - the above only adds a new column to an existing table.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Martin. It solved it. What a stupid SQL mistake i was doing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Replace
`EXEC (@SQLString)`

with
`EXEC @SQLString`

Comment: This causes the production of another error `Could not find stored procedure 'ALTER TABLE TableEx ADD ColumnEx NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL'.`

Comment: Thanks @Aishvarya. But that line never seemed a problem as I tested running **CREATE** statement separately with that _EXEC_ line working absolutely fine.